# Duplicate interface definition for class 'RCTBridge' error after react-native link

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-linking

After doing a react-native link to link font assets in my package.json :

```
"rnpm": {
   "assets": ["./assets/fonts/"]
}
```

I got several errors in xcode when trying to run react-native run-ios :

> Duplicate interface definition for class 'RCTBridge'

[image]

It seems to be a problem with include files, if you guys have any clues ..

Thx

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue.

In my case that problem occur after add react-native-fabric library.
So I'm do following steps.

1) open **SMXAnswers.h** then change **#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"** to

```
#if __has_include(<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>)
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#else
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#endif
```

2) open **SMXAnswers.m** then change following

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"  
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"  
#import "RCTBridge.h"
```

to

```
#if __has_include(<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>)
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#else
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#endif

#if __has_include(<React/RCTBridge.h>)
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#else
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#endif

#if __has_include(<React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>)
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#else
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#endif
```

It's may solve your issue.
This solution is working for me.